# no access to a java static method from scala

Tags: scala, static, scala-java-interop, mixed

I created a program with java and scala mixed, but I am faced to an error while trying to call a java static method from scala.Here is the code:

```
object GestionBasesScala {

  def sors_tout_de_suite() {

    application.launcher.append("SCALA : exit")
  }
}
```

the append method of the launcher class is like this (in java):

```
public static void append(String text) {

    if (name_of_file != null && name_of_file != "") {
        BufferedWriter bufWriter = null;
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(name_of_file, true);
            bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            // Insï¿½rer un saut de ligne
            bufWriter.newLine();
            bufWriter.write(text);
            bufWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
              //     Logger.getLogger(TextFileWriter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
            // null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bufWriter.close();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Logger.getLogger(TextFileWriter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                // null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I don't see what the error could be.

olivier

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Scala IDE/Eclipse, sometimes the in-editor compiler does not pick when static methods become created and/or updated.

Running `"Clean..."` on the project makes the error go away.

Comment: @lolveley : that's a shame. I assume you have "Build automatically" checked?

Answer (score 3):

`application.launcher` doesn't seem like a class name, are you sure it is? Shoudn't it be something like `LauncherClass.append("SCALA : exit")`?

EDIT1: After confirmation of the class name correctness I tried similar (a bit simplified) scenario, but I'm unable to reproduce behaviour described in Q. Following code works fine (did I miss something?):

```
package javastatic

object ScalaCaller extends App {
  def doStuff() {
     javastatic.JavaProvider.append("Scala here")
  }

  doStuff()
}
```

```java
package javastatic;

public class JavaProvider {
    public static void append(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

The error message from compiler could help. Please consider posting it.

Comment: hello, the package is application, the class name is launcher, and append is the method name, I'm sure.

Comment: hello, I would like to post it but it's impossible because the program uses a library named javaexe which transform it into a service, and because of that it does not gain access to the console (no println allowed); I tried to intercept the error message with this:

Comment: here is the code:
    `def sors_tout_de_suite() {
      try {
      val fileWriter = new FileWriter("logs\\zz.txt", true)
      val bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
      try{
         application.launcher.append("SCALA")
      }catch{
        case e:Exception => bufWriter.append(e.getMessage())
      }
      bufWriter.close()
    } catch {
      case e: IOException => {}
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `application.launcher._`